# Select Price range - MySQL Query

Tags: mysql

I need to select a price range from 0 to 50 euros.

I have this query:

`SELECT * FROM products WHERE price >= 0 AND price <= 50;`

Is there a better way to do it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is `BETWEEN`:

```
SELECT * FROM products WHERE price BETWEEN 0 AND 50;
```

but its behaviour is different. It selects values that are equal to the starting points as well, so `>=` instead of `>` and `<=` instead of `<`.

Comment: It does matter: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_between

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM products WHERE price BETWEEN 0 AND 50;
```

Comment: This equals to price >= 0 AND price <= 50, which is not the same as price > 0 AND price < 50

Comment: A float is never equal to 0 or 50 fix.

Comment: Whoever keeps prices in FLOAT asks for trouble.

Answer (score 0):

```
price value pass
$pricerange = explode('-', str_replace('$','',$searchValue['price_range']));  

 select * from tableName where  model='".$searchValue['model']."' and (price BETWEEN $pricerange[0] and $pricerange[1]) and status='active'
```

Comment: Please don't add code as comments. If it's part of your answer, edit it into the answer. Also, while this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please edit your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.